# Serve Vue,.js Pages with Express post with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express

I've an web application that can render sites embeded. The problem is that this site only send **POST** requests.

So i thought about serving it using express, then i searched a little here i got the following code to serve it, listening to all **GET** requests as vuetify pages:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname, '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
 console.log("Listening at http://%s:%s/", hostname, port);
});
```

Then I thought to add a post method to, receiving the parameters the page sends:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname, '/dist/index.html');
});
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname, '/dist/index.html');
});

app.post('/data', (req, res) => {
 const id = req.body.id;
 res.sendFile(__dirname, '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {

 console.log("Listening at http://%s:%s/", hostname, port);
});
```

How do i pass this argument to vue?

Is this the best way to serve vue with a post request?

Answer (score 0):

You are only sending the `index.html` file, there are other important files generated by `vue.js`.

In the following file I have a working middleware to serve a vue application which is built in `../../../frontend/dist/`.
https://github.com/marekvospel/libregifts/blob/next/apps/backend/src/router/index.ts

The only important thing is the 2 middleware functions. You can replace the '/api' condition with a method check.

```js
if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api')) next()
```

Comment: but  how can i get the req parameters in vue?

Comment: Vuejs is a client-side framework, there is no simple way to do that.

Comment: I aware of that, but that is my main problem.
Is there a way to send a parameter to a vue page if the url req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api')=true?

Comment: You can't simply send data to a vue page, you would need to append a script, that sets a global variable and read it later in the vue app, which could make your app XSS vulnerable

Comment: There should be a different fully client-side solution to your problem, if you're trying to send a form, the browser shouldn't be sending a post request, as vue can't handle that. You should make an event handler, that cancels the post api request, and does the request without refreshing the site.